# Error 500--Internal Server Error : OracleADF + SOAP web serice

Tags: soap, oracle-adf

When i run the JDeveloper( version 12c) and use ADF framework to create a web application, i create a business components and use the data control to drag and drop table from database, but when i run the application the web-logic give me this error (Error 500--Internal Server Error),  Below is the full Error Log. Please help me to solve the problem

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error

oracle.jbo.JboException: JBO-29114 ADFContext is not setup to process messages for this exception. Use the exception stack trace and error code to investigate the root cause of this exception. Root cause error code is JBO-29000. Error message parameters are {0=oracle.adf.model.adapter.AdapterException, 1=DCA-40002: The WSDL document is invalid due to the following reason : null.}
at oracle.adf.model.adapter.DataControlFactoryImpl.createSession(DataControlFactoryImpl.java:228)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCDataControlReference.getDataControl(DCDataControlReference.java:274)
at oracle.adf.model.BindingContext.instantiateDataControl(BindingContext.java:1416)
at oracle.adf.model.dcframe.DataControlFrameImpl.doFindDataControl(DataControlFrameImpl.java:1906)
at oracle.adf.model.dcframe.DataControlFrameImpl.internalFindDataControl(DataControlFrameImpl.java:1768)
at oracle.adf.model.dcframe.DataControlFrameImpl.findDataControl(DataControlFrameImpl.java:1728)
at oracle.adf.model.BindingContext.internalFindDataControl(BindingContext.java:1549)
at oracle.adf.model.BindingContext.get(BindingContext.java:1499)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCUtil.findSpelObject(DCUtil.java:340)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.evaluateParameterWithElCheck(DCBindingContainer.java:1521)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.findDataControl(DCBindingContainer.java:1627)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlActionBinding.internalGetDataControl(JUCtrlActionBinding.java:588)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlActionBinding.getDataControl(JUCtrlActionBinding.java:648)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlActionBinding.isOperationEnabled(JUCtrlActionBinding.java:336)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlActionBinding.isActionEnabled(JUCtrlActionBinding.java:300)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlActionBinding.getEnabled(JUCtrlActionBinding.java:1922)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlActionBinding.internalGet(JUCtrlActionBinding.java:2016)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlActionBinding.internalGet(FacesCtrlActionBinding.java:368)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCControlBinding.get(DCControlBinding.java:763)
at javax.el.MapELResolver.getValue(MapELResolver.java:199)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:139)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstNot.getValue(AstNot.java:63)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.bean.FacesBeanImpl.getProperty(FacesBeanImpl.java:73)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.ButtonRenderer.getDisabled(ButtonRenderer.java:449)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.ButtonRenderer.encodeAll(ButtonRenderer.java:284)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1650)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:538)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:1230)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:660)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:677)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAllChildrenInContext(RichRenderer.java:3284)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.FormRenderer.encodeAll(FormRenderer.java:275)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1650)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:538)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:1230)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:660)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:677)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAllChildrenInContext(RichRenderer.java:3284)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.DocumentRenderer.encodeAll(DocumentRenderer.java:1428)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1650)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:538)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:1230)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.component.AdfViewRoot.encodeAll(AdfViewRoot.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.renderView(ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.java:101)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.renderView(ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.java:101)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl$ChangeApplyingVDLWrapper.renderView(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:338)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:170)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.ResponseRenderManager.runRenderView(ResponseRenderManager.java:52)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._renderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:1228)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executeRenderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:1040)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:332)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:254)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:651)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:194)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:354)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:232)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:141)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:649)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:124)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:232)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:224)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3654)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3620)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2423)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2258)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1626)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1586)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: oracle.adf.model.adapter.AdapterException: JBO-29114 ADFContext is not setup to process messages for this exception. Use the exception stack trace and error code to investigate the root cause of this exception. Root cause error code is DCA-40002. Error message parameters are {0=null}
at oracle.adfinternal.model.adapter.webservice.WSModel.createModelFromWSDL(WSModel.java:725)
at oracle.adfinternal.model.adapter.webservice.WSModel.(WSModel.java:215)
at oracle.adfinternal.model.adapter.webservice.WSDefinition.createWSModel(WSDefinition.java:1922)
at oracle.adfinternal.model.adapter.webservice.WSDefinition.loadDefaultModel(WSDefinition.java:1917)
at oracle.adfinternal.model.adapter.webservice.WSDefinition.loadDCOperations(WSDefinition.java:1905)
at oracle.adfinternal.model.adapter.webservice.WSDefinition.createDataControl(WSDefinition.java:800)
at oracle.adf.model.adapter.DataControlFactoryImpl.createSession(DataControlFactoryImpl.java:202)
... 111 more
```

Comment: `The WSDL document is invalid due to the following reason : null.` does it mean something?

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/ to analyze whether WSDL is correct / service is up etc .